# Cannot find module 'ask-sdk' AND Unable to import module 'index' when packaged with Alexa CLI

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Why is my skill not working? It was made with the Alexa CLI, but I get multiple errors in cloudwatch:

```
 "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'ask-sdk'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:6:15)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
  ]
}

START RequestId: 8d7ecc70-7308-11e8-a831-fd4af108282c Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
END RequestId: 8d7ecc70-7308-11e8-a831-fd4af108282c
REPORT RequestId: 8d7ecc70-7308-11e8-a831-fd4af108282c  Duration: 1.47 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB
```

Alexa CLI Says everything was packaged with no errors:

> ```
> C:\Windows\System32\Premium_GlobalWarmingFacts>ask deploy
> -------------------- Update Skill Project --------------------
> Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxxxxxxx
> Skill deployment finished.
> Model deployment finished.
> Lambda deployment finished.
> Lambda function(s) updated:
>   [URI] arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:ask-custom-Premium_GlobalWarmingFacts-default
> In-skill product deployment finished.
> In-skill product(s) updated:
>   [ID] amzn1.adg.product.3e8c2107-29b7-4976-86aa-5b140bfeb9fb [FILE] isps\entitlement\globalwarming_pack.json
>   [ID] amzn1.adg.product.fe25638b-5806-4782-95bc-281020966118 [FILE] isps\entitlement\history_pack.json
>   [ID] amzn1.adg.product.186a8b85-0c7e-4d53-99e7-fc19c661c0e2 [FILE] isps\entitlement\animals_pack.json
>   [ID] amzn1.adg.product.3334840f-209b-49f0-b713-06de28f35797 [FILE] isps\subscription\all_access.json
> Your skill is now deployed and enabled in the development stage.
> Try invoking the skill by saying “Alexa, open {your_skill_invocation_name}” or simulate an invocation via the `ask simulate` command.
> ```

Here are the file directories: [file directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Mav.png)

> .ask
>   --config
>
> isps
>   --entitlement
>   --subscription
>
> lambda
>   --custom
>
> models
>   --En-us.JSON

Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Try adding `ask-sdk` explicitly from your Alexa Skill Builder.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I see an Alexa-sdk folder in the projects dorectory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant aws console. Add ask-sdk in your aws console.

Comment: Ok but about about the unable to import index?

Comment: Check this and confirm. https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Example-of-Alexa-skill-in-Python--MarvelFunFacts#change-your-environment